# Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =,!=,<,<=,>,>= or when the subquery is used as an expression

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have no idea why this brings up an error. Obviously, when I take out either one of the `THEN` subqueries it works fine but, unfortunately, I must have both select statements in. Is there a workaround?

```sql
SELECT
CASE
  WHEN ISNULL((
    SELECT xapIMCostingMethod
    FROM ProductionProperties), 0) = 2
  THEN isnull((
    SELECT cast(round((intUnitMaterialCost) \* (- (imtInventoryQuantityReceived) + imtScrapQuantity), 2) AS NUMERIC(36, 2))
    FROM PartTransactionCosts
    WHERE intPartTransactionID = imtPartTransactionID
    AND intCostType = 2), 0)
  ELSE isnull((
    SELECT cast(round((intUnitMaterialCost) \* (- (imtInventoryQuantityReceived) + imtScrapQuantity), 2) AS NUMERIC(36, 2))
    FROM PartTransactionCosts
    WHERE intPartTransactionID = imtPartTransactionID
    AND intCostType = 1), 0)
  END AS ActMatCost
FROM PartTransactions
```

I need the query to execute each `SELECT` separately.

Comment: it is very hard to read, but run all selects separately or add to all a TOP 1

Comment: You are comparing the ProductionPropertiesIs.xapIMCostingMethod with the value 2. So, there is only one row in the ProductionProperties table? Or have you forgotton to add a where clause? Maybe one that correlates with the row in your main query?

Comment: It seems PartTransactionCosts may have more than one row for the same intPartTransactionID  and intPartTransactionID. Check with `SELECT intPartTransactionID, intPartTransactionID FROM PartTransactionCosts GROUP BY intPartTransactionID, intPartTransactionID HAVING COUNT(*) > 1;`. If that's not bad data, perhaps you want `SUM`.

Comment: Workaround to what? You have two subqueries that can return more that one row. What do you want to happen when several rows are coming? A [mcve] would make this clearer.